# vagrant laravel homestead http server IP address

Tags: laravel, http, server, vagrant, homestead

After running "vagrant up", I cannot seem to access the http server in my browser when accessing "http://192.168.10.10/". I just get a "404 File Not Found" error.

Below are my config files and the log from running "vagrant up".

Thanks
A.

yaml file:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/Vagrant/Homestead/homestead.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: ~/Code/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - homestead
```

Vagrantfile:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

Log from "vagrant up":

```
C:\Users\Anders\Vagrant\Homestead>vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.0.12
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.16
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
GuestAdditions seems to be installed (5.0.16) correctly, but not running.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.0.12
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.16
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]
bash: line 4: vboxadd: command not found
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.0.12
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.16
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used

Restarting VM to apply changes...
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Anders/Vagrant/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Code => C:/Users/Anders/Code
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

C:\Users\Anders\Vagrant\Homestead>
```

Comment: If you're using any firewall, try to turn it off for some time.

Comment: Hi Alex - tried switching off Windows Firewall (host) but still have that problem. The vagran box doesn't run a firewall I believe.

Comment: If you're using Windows, set `map` (under `folder`) in `homestead.yaml` to something like: `c:\projects\my_laravel_project` instead of `~/Code`. After that run `vagrant provision`.

Comment: done -> thanks it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows, set `map` (under `folder`) in `homestead.yaml` to something like: `c:\projects\my_laravel_project` instead of `~/Code`. After that run `vagrant provision`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the configurations. But when you type that address you should have something like `index.html` inside your default mapped folder.

There could be a device using `192.168.10.10` as it could be in use within your actual home network. If that is the case try changing it.